# Draw the Serpinski Triangle

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, fractal

For today's fractal challenge, draw at least 5 iterations of Sierpinski's triangle! (Shown below is Sierpinski's trinagle)

[image]

The resolution of the image must be sufficent that the smallest triangles are at least one pixel in size, and all triangles should be approximately equillateral - pixel art that draws a right-triangle variant will be appreciated, but not accepted. Shortest code in bytes wins!